# SQL Query with multiple tables and joins

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have multiple tables - User / event / booking / location - from which I need to collect data.

I have NO SQL skills, and am just trying to stitch something together. So far I can get all user data and the booking data with the following query:

```
    SELECT ds_usermeta.first_name, ds_usermeta.last_name, 
       ds_usermeta.phone_number, ds_usermeta.mobile_number, ds_usermeta.user_emerg_name,
       ds_usermeta.user_emerg_rel, ds_usermeta.user_emerg_phone, 
       ds_em_bookings.booking_date, ds_em_bookings.booking_comment

FROM 
(
  SELECT user_id, 
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name'   THEN meta_value END) first_name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'last_name'    THEN meta_value END) last_name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'phone_number' THEN meta_value END) phone_number,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'mobile_number'      THEN meta_value END) mobile_number,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'user_emerg_name'      THEN meta_value END) user_emerg_name,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'user_emerg_rel'      THEN meta_value END) user_emerg_rel,
         MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'user_emerg_phone'      THEN meta_value END) user_emerg_phone
    FROM ds_usermeta
   WHERE EXISTS
  (
      SELECT *
        FROM ds_em_bookings
       WHERE ds_em_bookings.person_id = ds_usermeta.user_id
  )
   GROUP BY ds_usermeta.user_id
) ds_usermeta JOIN ds_em_bookings
    ON ds_usermeta.user_id = ds_em_bookings.person_id
    ORDER BY ds_em_bookings.event_id
```

Since user data is stored in rows it can't be simply SELECTED - example of User Meta Data Table:

```
umeta_id    user_id    meta_key    meta_value
-----------------------------------------------
   1           1       nickname    mikesmith
   2           1       first_name  Mike
   3           1       last_name   Smith
```

My problem is that the booking data in ds_em_bookings is just IDs. To get a 'nice name' I need to pull it from ds_em_events by matching the ID. I also need to pull the location name from ds_em_locations by matching the ID from ds_em_events.

Then I hope to have something like this

```
First_name | Last_name | booking_date | event_name | location_name
```

Only with ALL the user fields above. I've tried multiple combinations based on this:

```
(
    SELECT event_name
    FROM ds_em_events
    WHERE ds_em_events.event_id = ds_em_bookings.event_id
    JOIN ds_em_bookings
    ON ds_em_events.event_id = ds_em_bookings.event_id
)
(
    SELECT location_name
    FROM ds_em_locations
    WHERE ds_em_locations.location_id = ds_em_events.location_id
    LEFT JOIN ds_em_events
    ON ds_em_locations.location_id = ds_em_events.location_id

  )
```

But cannot work out how/where to put this or something similar in order to pull the event_name from ds_em_events and the location (the ID for which is in ds_em_events table) for each booking that is found.

Sorry it's a long post but I hope that's enough detail to be clear. Any help welcome - please remember I'm a newbie -just starting with SQL.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Mike. I'd like to suggest you make a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and post it, so we can see your tables and have some data examples.

Comment: That would have certainly made answering easier! :) It's a simple problem but the names and structure of those tables is horrible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join on more than one table so simply chain all joins to your main query and select the columns from those tables:

```
SELECT ds_usermeta.first_name,
        ds_usermeta.last_name,
        ...
        ds_em_bookings.booking_date,
        ds_em_bookings.booking_comment,
        ds_em_events.event_name,
        ds_em_locations.location_name

FROM 
    (SELECT user_id, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'first_name'   THEN meta_value END) first_name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'last_name'    THEN meta_value END) last_name,
        ...
        FROM ds_usermeta
        GROUP BY ds_usermeta.user_id
    ) ds_usermeta
INNER JOIN ds_em_bookings ON ds_usermeta.user_id = ds_em_bookings.person_id
INNER JOIN ds_em_events ON ds_em_events.event_id = ds_em_bookings.event_id
INNER JOIN ds_em_locations ON ds_em_locations.location_id = ds_em_events.location_id
ORDER BY ds_em_bookings.event_id
```

Note that when you have a `JOIN` you shouldn't also need to compare IDs in a  `WHERE` clause. Use `INNER JOIN` instead of `WHERE EXISTS` because that would eliminate all rows where there is no corresponding row in the other table.

Also note that a `LEFT JOIN` will list all rows from the left table - if there's no corresponding row in the right table, it will show NULLs. Note the subtle difference in the example. You've done:

```
SELECT location_name
FROM ds_em_locations
LEFT JOIN ds_em_events ON ds_em_locations.location_id = ds_em_events.location_id
```

which joins events to locations and gives you all locations, even ones that have no events - however your main query is going the other way so we do

```
JOIN ds_em_locations ON ds_em_locations.location_id = ds_em_events.location_id
```

which joins the locations to events/bookings so it won't show locations without bookings. If you want to show all such rows, you might need to do a `RIGHT JOIN` or similar.

[The Wiki article on JOINs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join) is very thorough - read it!

Comment: Thank you Boris - this worked perfectly. IYou've been a life-saver here. Much appreciated.